# Unable to unserialize value. Magento version 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, exception, captcha, unserialize

I have had this problem for some time now, frontend I can't replicate this error it happens to me 3/4 times a day, in var/log I see this error.

```
[2023-04-17 08:25:43] main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. {"report_id":"a204ac71d57096d59e5f11982cbea87217ee06fe38d76ac4f2382803b564a412","exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to unserialize value. at vendor/magepow/sizechart/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:15)"} []

Which generates a report id {"0":"Unable to unserialize value.","1":"#1 Magento\\Captcha\\Model\\Customer\\Plugin\\AjaxLogin->aroundExecute() called at [vendor \/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]
```

I tried to edit the json.php file with the various is_serilized and other solutions found on the internet but still the same problem.
I set the google lv3 invisible captcas with related api and everything works fine.
Can anyone help me?